# SQL Query Column Update

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
+-------------------------------+
| id  subscriber       package  |
+-------------------------------+
| 1   5553288          heart    |
| 2   4443365          love     |
| 3   5553288          love     |
| 4   3332353          love     |
| 5   5845569          tech     |
+-------------------------------+
```

I'd like to update this table.

If a subscriber has signed up for package `love` only, I'd like to change it to `heart`.

And if a subscriber has package `love` & `heart`. I'd like to delete the row for `love` and leave them with the row for `heart`.

I tried using this

```
UPDATE subscriber
SET package=`heart
WHERE package=`love`
```

`

Bit it wont work because there are subscribers who are in both packages

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: i tried                                                                  SELECT DISTINCT subscriber FROM subscriber
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE package = 'love' AND subscriber = subscriber)
    AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE package = 'heart' AND subscriber = subscriber)                                      BUT this only shows me the subscribers that are in both packages.  I need help updating. and ive searched but cant find. Ps; im an amateur

Comment: Please add your code to the question, not to a comment. And to update a table you need the `UPDATE` command, not `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a good select statement for your spec, you've already done most of the hard work.  It's usually trivial to make a DML statement from that, even if you use the whole thing as your where clause or join to it as a derived table.

```
-- If a subscriber has signed up for package love only, I'd like to change it to heart.
update MyTable
set package = 'heart'
where subscriber in (
        -- Get subscribers with only love
        select subscriber
        from MyTable
        group by subscriber
        -- This having clause will handle duplicate subscriptions to love
        having max(package) = min(package)
            and max(package) = 'love'
    );

-- And if a subscriber has package love & heart. I'd like to delete the row for love and leave them with the row for heart.
delete from MyTable
where package = 'love'
    and subscriber in (
        -- Get subscribers with heart
        select subscriber
        from MyTable
        where package = 'heart'
    )
    and subscriber in (
        -- Get subscribers with love
        select subscriber
        from MyTable
        where package = 'love'
    );
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. ill try using it now. Can i run these two queries at once? or should i try them individually?

Comment: SQL error:
`
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "subscriber"
LINE 2: delete subscriber ` This is the error i get when i run the second Query

Comment: All i had to do was add `FROM` to tims ` delete subscriber ` statement.

Comment: @user2183180 Is this postgresql?

Comment: After running it though i do a select and i see the package love still coming up

Comment: After running it do you still have subscribers with both?